# Warning This System have been rebooted greater than or equal to 4 times..... Please re-download image

Tags: cmd.exe

```
Warning
This System have been rebooted greater than or equal to 4 times.....
Please re-download image!
```

I looked everywhere about this message and I didn't find any info on Google.

Does anyone know what it means.

I got it when I tied to access cmd.exe

[Message received when typing cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHGrH.png)

Comment: Might be inept malware... the message contains grammatical errors. Not a Microsoft error message, I hope.

Comment: Possible duplicate.......https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: [Here’s the sourcecode](https://pastebin.com/fg2uccsN) of this thing. If you can see it, the factory image probably wasn’t properly applied.

Answer (score 1):

No malware involved, this problem happens on Acer machines.

You probably did like me and went Start Menu / Execute then typed `cmd`.

If you check carefully you'll see you are not executing `cmd.exe` but **`$Acer$.cmd`** which has something to do with recovery (I did not search further).

The file is in the `C:\Windows\System32` folder. I simply deleted it.